# onbeforeunload doesn't seem to always be trigerred

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

Here's a minimum example -

> **index.php**

```
<?php
$count = file_get_contents("count.txt") + 0;
file_put_contents("$count.txt [loaded]", '');
file_put_contents("count.txt", $count + 1);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <p> hi there </p>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript">
var id = "<?php echo $count; ?>";
</script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

> **script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    $.post("unloader.php", { id : id });
});

});
```

---

> **unloader.php**

```
<?php
file_put_contents("$_POST[id] [unloaded]", '');
```

When I open the webpage, a file is created with the count number as its name.
When I close the tab jquery requests unloader.php which is just a standalone script that creates a file with the count number as its name too.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
I mean the opening file is always created. But sometimes the file which has to be created on closing is not made.
Any idea where the issue occured ?

Comment: It's likely because you're binding the `onbeforeunload` event to inside the DOMReady function. If the process of putting the contents takes a while, the DOM may not be ready when the user unloads the page.

Comment: @BenM sadly not, I tried with a blank page and waiting for a while before closing. And the file still sometimes doesn't get created on the server.

Comment: Can you explain the point of this? You just create a blank file on the server called `$_POST[id] [unloaded]`? Why not just use a cookie or a session?

Comment: @BenM so I can check how much time a personal visitor stayed on the page, I compare the time load and unload

Comment: Again, why use a file system for a DB's job? Or better still, use Google Analytics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (reliably) make AJAX calls when unloading the page. Because it's being unloaded, anything still in progress will be dropped.

If the browser's fast enough with the AJAX call (or the server's slow enough in responding to the new page load) then you should see a result, but it is not at all reliable.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I think i'll go with a main loop that sends a request every second updating a distant file so I can barely know how long the user was staying on the page. Sounds quite messy but that'll do it.

Comment: Every *second*??? Good luck... Personally I just keep a field in the database that I update with the time a user last loaded a page, and assume them to be online for the 15 minutes that follow. If you need a constant ping, 30 seconds to a minute is a good starting point.